# plotly.js using high memory

Tags: json, symfony, twig, plotly.js

Ployly.js is using a lot of memory when using a lot of data points.

I am trying to trouble shoot slow loading with a site that uses plotly.js to display the graphs. I Think i narrowed it down to the datapoints being used is causing it to use a lot of memory. For example, with a plot that just uses 1500 data points (Date / integer) it was wracking up 500mb of a page download. I was wondering if anyone has seen this issue or found a fix? So far my google fu is coming up short.

example twig template

```
            <ul class="list-group">
                <div id="flow_data_cmFlowStatsFMYN2AFlow1{{ counter }}" class="collapse" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"><!-- Plotly chart will be drawn inside this DIV --></div>
            </ul>
            <script>
                var flow = {
                    x: [
                        {% for d in n['flow_data_datetime'] %}
                        '{{ d|date('F j, Y g:i:s:a') }}',
                        {% endfor %}
                    ],
                    y: [
                        {% for d in n['flow_data_cmFlowStatsFMYN2AFlow1'] %}
                        '{{ d }}',
                        {% endfor %}
                    ],
                    name: 'FMY - N2A - {{ n['flow_data_flow_name'] }}',
                    type: 'scatter',
                    hovertemplate: 'FMY - N2A - {{ n['flow_data_flow_name'] }}, %{y} (Frames)',
                };

                var flowDropped = {
                    x: [
                        {% for d in n['flow_data_datetime'] %}
                        '{{ d|date('F j, Y g:i:s:a') }}',
                        {% endfor %}
                    ],
                    y: [
                        {% for d in n['flow_data_cmFlowStatsFMYDN2AFlow1'] %}
                        '{{ d }}',
                        {% endfor %}
                    ],
                    name: 'FMY and Dropped - N2A - {{ n['flow_data_flow_name'] }}',
                    type: 'scatter',
                    hovertemplate: 'FMY and Dropped - N2A - {{ n['flow_data_flow_name'] }}, %{y} (Frames)',
                };


                var data = [
                    flow,flowDropped
                ];
                var layout = {
                    width: 1000,
                    height: 700,
                    margin: {
                        l: 100,
                        r: 50,
                        b: 220,
                        t: 100,
                        pad: 10
                    },
                    title: 'FLOW :: {{ n['flow_data_flow_name'] }}',
                    showlegend: true,
                    legend: {
                        x: 1,
                        y: 1
                    },
                    xaxis: {
                        title: 'Date / Time Pulled',
                        automargin: true,
                        height: 1000,
                        titlefont: {
                            family: 'Courier New, monospace',
                            size: 18,
                            color: '#7f7f7f'
                        }
                    },
                    yaxis: {
                        title: 'Frames Marked Yellow N2A',
                        automargin: true,
                        titlefont: {
                            family: 'Courier New, monospace',
                            size: 18,
                            color: '#7f7f7f'
                        }
                    }
                };
```

Slow loading, When looking at page statistics, the download size gets to 300 - 500mb page size.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure memory issue will solved by this article.
But I'm sure it will faster than before.

First of all, change "type" scatter -> scattergl.

For more information refer to [How do I make Plotly faster](https://www.somesolvedproblems.com/2018/07/how-do-i-make-plotly-faster.html?m=1)